# How to modify/add a new objectClass to an entry in OpenLDAP php

Tags: php, openldap

I have an entry in the AD(Active Directory) which has only **person** objectclass with attributes of cn and sn.
Now I want to add one more objectclass of **organizationalPerson** to insert **postalCode** attribute using **LDAP**.

I am new to LDAP, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not detailed enough to get any context. If your requirement is just to add an organizationalPerson objectClass to an existing object, you can do so through command line or using phpldapadmin/ Apache Directory Studio for GUI.

You can refer [this](https://devopsideas.com/openldap-tutorial-practical-realtime-implemetnation-and-integration/) site to get a basic understanding on how to configure and use openldap